# Grouping by two bit columns

Tags: mysql

I wanted to `GROUP BY` two bit columns where the value is true. But I have two column separated how can I join them where bit column is true?

```
SELECT     employees.employee_id, employees.last_name, 
           employees.first_name, employees.middle_name, 
           employee_role.isAdmin, employee_role.isEmployee
FROM       employees
INNER JOIN employee_role ON employee_role.employee_id = employees.id
INNER JOIN passwords ON passwords.id = employees.password_id
WHERE      employees.employee_id = pIN_employeeId AND passwords.password = pIN_password;
```

Draft Output:

```
employee_id | last_name | first_name | middle_name | isAdmin | isEmployee
------------+-----------+------------+-------------+---------+------------
  20140540  | Armstrong | Billie Joe |     A       |   0     |    1
  20140540  | Armstrong | Billie Joe |     A       |   1     |    0
```

Expected Output:

```
employee_id | last_name | first_name | middle_name | isAdmin | isEmployee
------------+-----------+------------+-------------+---------+------------
  20140540  | Armstrong | Billie Joe |     A       |   1     |    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Max` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT     employees.employee_id, employees.last_name, 
           employees.first_name, employees.middle_name, 
           Max(employee_role.isAdmin), 
           Max(employee_role.isEmployee)
FROM       employees
INNER JOIN employee_role ON employee_role.employee_id = employees.id
INNER JOIN passwords     ON passwords.id = employees.password_id
WHERE      employees.employee_id = pIN_employeeId AND passwords.password = pIN_password
GROUP BY   employees.employee_id;
```

If *employee_id* is not the primary key, you will need to add the other columns in the `GROUP BY` clause as well:

```
GROUP BY   employees.employee_id, employees.last_name, 
           employees.first_name, employees.middle_name;
```

In other databases it is even required to add these columns.

If you only want to include employees that have a record with the *isAdmin* bit set, AND also have a record with the *isEmployee* set, excluding all other cases, then add the `HAVING` clause like this:

```
SELECT     employees.employee_id, employees.last_name, 
           employees.first_name, employees.middle_name, 
           Max(employee_role.isAdmin), 
           Max(employee_role.isEmployee)
FROM       employees
INNER JOIN employee_role ON employee_role.employee_id = employees.id
INNER JOIN passwords     ON passwords.id = employees.password_id
WHERE      employees.employee_id = pIN_employeeId AND passwords.password = pIN_password
GROUP BY   employees.employee_id
HAVING     Max(employee_role.isAdmin) = 1 
AND        Max(employee_role.isEmployee) = 1;
```

Comment: I got a exception where SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Then you need to mention the other non-Max-ed columns in the `GROUP BY` clause as well. See extra paragraph I added in the middle of my answer.

Comment: Many thanks to this. I see where I got wrong. I need to `GROUP BY` also the other column with the help of `MAX` and `MIN` function. `GROUP BY` also did the trick :)